# Show the index blade on 404 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to show the index page if the route is not found.

I have modified the App\Exceptions\Handler like so and that did not work

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($this->isHttpException($exception) || $exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return view('app.index');
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: I think you should redirect to your main page, like: ` return redirect('app/index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my mistake I can accomplish the same thing by rooting all requests to the index.

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'FrontEndController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```